# Delete button not working in dynamic rows

Tags: magento2, dynamic-rows

I have added dynamic rows using generic block method.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Blocks\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray;
use Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer;

class ItemRow extends AbstractFieldArray
{
    protected $authSession;

    public function __construct(Context $context, array $data = [], ? SecureHtmlRenderer $secureRenderer = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data, $secureRenderer);
    }

    protected function _prepareToRender()
    {
        $this->addColumn('name', ['label' => __('name') , ]);
        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add');
    }
}
```

Using this, I am able to generate dynamic rows and save data to database and see existing data once added.  Though when page is loaded, it is giving below error in console and I am not able to delete existing rows. Though if I click on add new button and delete new row before saving it, that row is getting deleted.

[image]

Comment: Facing same issue. Any solution?